# How to show image with grey color which covers the entire image in react-native fast image(not the background entire image)

Tags: react-native, react-native-image

I need to show an image which the view is in grey color. (i.e) entire screen need to show the grey not the background alone above the image also needs to change. I am using react-native-fast-image package

Answer (score 0):

You might need to add progressive image to do that.
Use a small sized image lets say of 2kb to show initially till the image has not loaded and when the image loads up show the original image.

[Progressive image blog!](https://medium.com/react-native-training/progressive-image-loading-in-react-native-e7a01827feb7)

This is exactly what you are looking for. : )

Comment: Here I need not to show any blurred image while loading. I need to show the exact image with the overlay change. So the image quality is good and above the image it have the loading icon.

Comment: Render the same image as progressive with low resolution . Use `ImageBackground` to add a spinner also over that. Note - Only `Image` wont allow you to add a spinner. And then use the function of onLoadEnd to show the original image. https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/image#onloadstart